# How to run VSCode Code Spell Checker extension on an entire folder?/

Tags: visual-studio-code

Street Side Software's [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) is a great VSCode extension to tease out typos. I mainly interact with it on a per source file basis where opening the file in the editor triggers the spell check rundown. Is there some way to enact a spell check on an entire directory, maybe even opening all affected files?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the extension but it is still an open [ISSUE 376](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/issues/376) on plugin's github page so it is possible, in future, this feature might be added.

As an alternative, as suggested in the same issue, you can use [cspell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cspell) utility to spell check project directory.